# How to set visibility of ionic-card?

Tags: ionic-framework

In my project I use native storage

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
      console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
      this.nativeStorage.getItem('Arrivaldetails')
        .then(
          data =>{
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data.arrivaltime));

            this.getFlightDetails(data.fligtdetails,data.arrivaltime,data.departuretime);
          },


          error => console.error(error)

        );
    });
```

and I want to check the native storage is null or not.
If it is null, I want to hide the  ion-card and display a text view and 
if not null I want to display the ion-card and hide the text view

```
<ion-card">

    <ion-card-content>
      <p><span>{{FullDetails.departureAirportFsCode}}</span></p>

    </ion-card-content>
```

Comment: you can use ng-hide or ng-show for hide and show particular section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional variable to check if is it empty or not.

```
let showData: boolean = false;
```

And your function should looks like

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
    console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('Arrivaldetails')
    .then(data => {
        if (data){                
            this.showData = true;
            this.getFlightDetails(data.fligtdetails,data.arrivaltime,data.departuretime);
        }
        else 
            this.showData = false;
    },error => {
        console.error(error);     
    });
});
```

Then in HTML you can use:

```
<ion-card *ngIf="showData">
    <ion-card-content>
      <p><span>{{FullDetails.departureAirportFsCode}}</span></p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<div *ngIf="!showData">
   your text here
</div>
```

I hope it helps.